# how to build private route system in React

Tags: reactjs, typescript

my App declaration looks like this

```
function App() {
  const [loggedIn, setLoggedIn] = useState(false);
  const [username, setUsername] = useState('')
  const [userId, setUserId] = useState(0)
  const [error, setError] = useState('')

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchSessionData(setLoggedIn, setUsername, setUserId, setError)
  }, [])
```

`fetchSessionData` calls the server and receives information about username and userId and sets the variables. Next i have routing

```
<Switch>
<Route exact path="/games/new">
              <PrivateRoute isLogged={loggedIn}>
                <MyComponent />
              </PrivateRoute>
            </Route>
<Switch/>
```

With `PrivateRoute` looking like this:

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ children, isLogged }: { children: JSX.Element, isLogged: boolean }): JSX.Element => {
    return (
        isLogged ? children : <Redirect to="/sign_in" />
    );
};
```

Its a simple system meant to assure that certain routes will only be accessible if the user is signed in. HOWEVER. Even if im actually signed in, the `isLogged` var seems to always be `false`.
I believe its because the routing part gets rendered before the answer from the server actually gets received and variables set.
Question is very simple, how to modify this architecture so the `loggedIn` variable is read after the response from the server?

Comment: read docs all details mentioned there.

Comment: can you link relevant doc parts?

Comment: https://reactrouter.com/en/main

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a `loading` state or equivalent (e.g. `loggedIn` state initialized as `null`, and interpreting this `null` value as "loading").

Then do not render your `<PrivateRoute>` component while you are still loading:

```
{
  loggedIn !== null && <PrivateRoute isLogged={loggedIn}>
    <MyComponent />
  </PrivateRoute>
}
```

Or handle the loading state within `<PrivateRoute>` to prevent redirecting before loaded:

```
const PrivateRoute = ({
  children,
  isLogged
}: {
  children: JSX.Element,
  isLogged: boolean | null
}): JSX.Element => {
  return (
    isLogged === null
      ? "Checking user account..."
      : isLogged
        ? children
        : <Redirect to="/sign_in" />
  );
};
```

Comment: i did something similar i think, introduced new variable 'isLoading' that is initially true and gets set to false after the response from the server. then with "isLoding && ...." the WHOLE routing is rendering conditionally and the whole thing works correctly, thank you sir

Answer (score 0):

First make sure that `loggedIn` state is changing.

- your problem might be because of state changing and if you use a function  to validate if the user is loggedIn or not. would be better.

You can use this code snippet I used for this exact matter.
I'm using React Router +6 here.

```
 <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="auth/*" element={<AuthPages />} />


        <Route path="/" element={<Navigate to="/admin/dashboard" />} />
        <Route
          path="admin/*"
          element={
            isAuthenticated() ? (
              <AdminRoutes />
            ) : (
              <Navigate to={'/auth/login'} />
            )
          }
        />
        <Route path="auth/login/verify" element={<TwoFactorPage />} />
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
```

> isAuthenticated is a simple function that checks if the user state has filled with data, and if so it will return true.